# Optional argument not getting set to \makebox through expl3 key assignment

Tags: expl3, key-value

The basic idea that I wanted was to create a key to pass a value that would inform `\makebox` how the contents of the box should be aligned.  Big fail here.

The intended contents of the `\makebox` are not passed as arguments to `\makebox` and I seem to have random components of my keys ignored or inserted into the text.

What's happening here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N  \l_aefl_position_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl { [l] }

\keys_define:nn { aefl }
    {
        pos   .code:n   = {
                            \str_case:nnn { #1 }
                            {
                                { left   } { \tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl {[l]} }
                                { center } { \tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl {}    }
                            }
                            {
                                { right } { \tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl {[r]} }
                            }
                          },
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aecurrfile}{ o }
    {
        \group_begin:
        \IfNoValueF{#1}{\keys_set:nn { aefl }{#1}}

        \makebox[0pt] \l_aefl_position_tl
                      { contents ~ of ~ my ~ box }
        \group_end:
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
unexpected & \verb=[l]=      & \aecurrfile                        \\
unexpected & \verb=[l]=      & Front \aecurrfile[pos=left] Back   \\
           &                 & Front \aecurrfile[pos=center] Back \\
unexpected & \verb=right[l]= & Front \aecurrfile[pos=right] Back
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

*EDIT*

Finally, I see why I'm getting the *unexpected* right in my output.  Argh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that when LaTeX looks for an optional argument, it needs to find a *literal* `[` and not one stored inside anything. So you need to expand `\l_aefl_position_tl` before `\makebox` looks for it. I'd probably go for something like

```
\use:x { \exp_not:N \makebox [0pt] \l_aefl_position_tl }
```

as you know that the content of `\l_aefl_position_tl` is 'safe'.

Comment: Ah ha!  I'd tried something like this, but I hadn't used the wrapper `\use:x { ... }` around the whole expression.

Comment: Thank you.  Now the need for the wrapper `\use:x` makes better sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

I would streamline the business. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N  \l_aefl_position_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl { \makebox[0pt][l] }

\keys_define:nn { aefl }
 {
  pos .choice:,
  pos / left   .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl { \makebox[0pt][l] },
  pos / right  .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl { \makebox[0pt][r] },
  pos / center .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_aefl_position_tl { \makebox[0pt]    },
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aecurrfile}{ O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { aefl } { #1 }
  \tl_use:N \l_aefl_position_tl { contents ~ of ~ my ~ box }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\parbox{10cm}{
Default:\\
\aecurrfile

Left:\\
\aecurrfile[pos=left]

Center:\\
\aecurrfile[pos=center]

Right:\\
\aecurrfile[pos=right]

}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was originally trying to use `.choice:n`.  I kept getting error messages.  So I went back to something I was more familiar with.  Thank you for this example of using `.choice:n`.

Comment: @A.Ellett Notice also the optional argument `O{}` rather than `o` and testing with `\IfNoValueF`: `\keys_set:nn` is perfectly happy to be fed with an empty list of key-value pairs.